# tutorial on crosscompiling .deb packages?

Tags: raspbian, debian, cross-compilation

I'd really like to get to know debian packaging for the RPi

I have read several useful tutorials on how to crosscompile with tools from

https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708

and some on setting up crosstool-ng

This lets me compile hello_world.c nicely for the Raspberry Pi - but i have a hard time working out how to get make and other build tools working.

Also read tutorials on how to run a qemu chroot environment, where i can debootstrap an raspbian install - this should make things simpler - but with some extra administration, and added overhead from the Qemu layer.
(http://superpiadventures.com/2012/07/development-environment/ is one good tutorial)

Reading about debian crosscompilation, it should be able to define a target architecture, and do something like "dpkg-buildpackage -aarmv6h" on x86_64 Debian, using source .debs i find on non-raspbian repositories.
(http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html)

I'm not clever enough to get it set up myself - perhaps a kind reader has written or found a useful tutorial on crosscompiling .deb packages ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way to build .deb packages targeting Debian or Rasbian is to compile the package on the machine or inside an emulated machine. Thus the recommended way to cross-compile a .deb for Raspberry Pi is to emulate a complete system using qemu on a X86 machine and use it to do the compiles.
[http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150302053420/http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way) (archive.org copy)

There is true cross-compile support build into the latest Debian and Ubuntu **sbuild** tool that you may use to compile or cross compile .deb packages, you can read how to use the cross compile features of **sbuild** by following the latest Debian/Ubuntu wiki guides, assuming you are running the latest Debian or Ubuntu developement branch.
http://wiki.debian.org/CrossBuildPackagingGuidelines
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CrossBuilding