# How to install GNUradio on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, gnuradio

Will it take the same procedure (like we install GNUradio in Ubuntu) or should we need something different. Please tell me in detail as i am a newbie on this side(Linux and raspberry pi). I am using Raspbian wheezy on raspberry pi.

Comment: You tagged the question with `gnuradio`. Is this what you are looking for? If so, please edit your question. [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/gnu.en.html) itself is a software project, of which many portions are already installed on your Pi.

Comment: There don't seem to be any binaries in the raspbian repo so you will have to build it ("Installing manually from source"): http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGR  Do not bother with their binaries either, they won't work on the pi.

Comment: I think this answer links to the important information: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5524/tutorial-on-crosscompiling-deb-packages. Also, there is a [debian package for Gnuradio](http://packages.debian.org/de/sid/gnuradio), so you should be able to compile it for the Pi.

Comment: Update: here is the wheezy gnuradio package page: http://packages.debian.org/de/wheezy/gnuradio

Comment: Maybe one of you guys can try it and formulate an answer for doing this.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" to your question. Upvote answers you like, this  is the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I forgot to check, but it seems there *is* actually a package for gnuradio in Raspbian wheezy: http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gnuradio/

So you should be able to install the package by running:

```
sudo apt-get install gnuradio
```

If you want do develop using gnuradio, make sure to also install `gnuradio-dev` and maybe also the different `libgnuradio*` packages (you can search for them using `apt-cache seardch libgnuradio`).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su -
echo "deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main">>/etc/apt/sources.list
```

check if listed in source file

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Get updates

```
apt-get update
```

install packages

```
apt-get install -y gnuradio
apt-get install -y gnuradio-dev
```

disable the the driver from using the USB DVB as a TV tuner card.

```
echo "blacklist dvb_usb_rtl28xxu">>/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf

apt-get install -y rtl-sdr gr-osmosdr
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2832", GROUP="adm", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="rtl_sdr"'>>/etc/udev/rules.d/20.rtlsdr.rules
```

Check if listed in rule file.

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/20.rtlsdr.rules
init 6
```

After the Pi reboots to test your device by running command.

```
rtl_test
```